# Plot Imshow on a Torus (lattice with PBC)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, mplot3d

Is there any "simple" solution in `matplotlib` or another Python package to plot a square lattice on a 2d torus (aka lattice with periodic boundary conditions)?

Assume i have a simple 2D array

```
# ...
a = np.random.random((50, 50))
plt.imshow(a)
```

[image]

I would like to wrap this plane into a torus, which can be achieved e.g. with

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
# Generating Torus Mesh
angle = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
theta, phi = np.meshgrid(angle, angle)
r, R = .25, 1.
X = (R + r * np.cos(phi)) * np.cos(theta)
Y = (R + r * np.cos(phi)) * np.sin(theta)
Z = r * np.sin(phi)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection = '3d')

ax.set_xlim3d(-1, 1)
ax.set_ylim3d(-1, 1)
ax.set_zlim3d(-1, 1)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride = 1, cstride = 1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

I thought about encoding somehow the information on `X` and `Y` value in a colormap to pass to `plot_surface`'s option `cmap`. The colormap shall have each color of the image according to content of array `a`.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question will be generalized as 'is there any simple solution to map a 2D plane onto a 3D surface?'  The Matplotlib third-party package, [S3Dlib](https://s3dlib.org/), may provide a relatively simple solution.  This package allows direct functional or image mapping onto predefined mesh 3D surfaces.  In cylindrical coordinates ( r,t,z ), functional mapping of a cylinder to a torus is:

```
def torusFunc(rtz) :
    r,t,z = rtz
    Z = np.sin(z*np.pi)/3
    R = r + np.cos(z*np.pi)/3
    return R,t,Z
```

Any face coordinate of N number of faces on a cylinder can be assigned a random value using:

```
def random_colors(rtz):
    r,t,z = rtz
    N = len(t)*len(z)
    return np.random.random(N)
```

Then using these two functions, a cylinder object is created, color assigned to each face, and then mapped to the toroidal geometry.  The object is added to the Axes3D with the result:

[image: colored torus]

For the above figure, shading and hignlighting were used to clarify the surface geometry.  The code is:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import s3dlib.surface as s3d

# 1. Define functions .....................................
def torusFunc(rtz) :
    r,t,z = rtz
    Z = np.sin(z*np.pi)/3
    R = r + np.cos(z*np.pi)/3
    return R,t,Z

np.random.seed(0)
def random_colors(rtz):
    r,t,z = rtz
    N = len(t)*len(z)
    return np.random.random(N)

# 2. Create and map the surface ...........................
torus = s3d.CylindricalSurface.grid(30,100,'r')
torus.map_cmap_from_op( random_colors, "viridis" )
torus.map_geom_from_op(  torusFunc ) 

# 3. Construct axes, add surface object, & show ...........
minmax,ticks = (-1.33,1.33), (-1,-.5,0,.5,1)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(1))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.set(xlim=minmax,  ylim=minmax,  zlim=minmax,
       xticks=ticks, yticks=ticks, zticks=ticks )
ax.set_title(torus.name)

ax.add_collection3d(torus.shade().hilite(.5))

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Image mapping can also be used similar to functional mapping.
Since mapping is visually obscured using a random colored image,  a earth surface image will be used to demonstrate this:

[image: earth surface image]

The image originated from the NASA [visible earth](https://visibleearth.nasa.gov/images/57752/blue-marble-land-surface-shallow-water-and-shaded-topography) catalog.
The following figure shows image mapping using planar, polar, cylindrical and spherical coordinate systems.

[image: four surfaces]

where the code is:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import s3dlib.surface as s3d

# 1. Define functions to examine ....................................
def planarFunc(xyz) : # Himmelblau
    x,y,z = xyz
    X,Y = 5*x, 5*y
    Z1 = np.square( X*X + Y - 11 )
    Z2 = np.square( Y*Y + X - 7  ) 
    Z = (Z1 + Z2)/500 - 1
    return x,y,Z

def screwFunc(rtz) :
    r,t,z = rtz
    T = 2*t
    Z = 0.2*(T - 2*np.pi)
    return r,T,Z

def torusFunc(rtz) :
    r,t,z = rtz
    Z = np.sin(z*np.pi)/3
    R = r + np.cos(z*np.pi)/3
    return R,t,Z

def swirlFunc(rtp) :
    r,t,p = rtp
    R = 0.4*(2 + np.sin(5*t + 3*p))
    return R,t,p
 
# 2. Setup and map surfaces .........................................
img_fname, rez = 'data/earth.png', 5

planar = s3d.PlanarSurface(rez,basetype='oct1')
planar.map_color_from_image(img_fname)
planar.map_geom_from_op(planarFunc)

screw = s3d.PolarSurface(rez, basetype='hex_s')
screw.map_color_from_image(img_fname)
screw.map_geom_from_op( screwFunc)

torus = s3d.CylindricalSurface(rez, basetype='squ_s')
torus.map_color_from_image(img_fname)
torus.map_geom_from_op(  torusFunc) 

swirl = s3d.SphericalSurface(rez)
swirl.map_color_from_image(img_fname)
swirl.map_geom_from_op( swirlFunc )

# 3. Construct figure, add surfaces, and plot ......................
minmax = (-.9,.9)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(1) )
for i,surface in enumerate( [planar,screw,torus,swirl] ) :
    ax = fig.add_subplot(221+i, projection='3d')
    ax.set(xlim=minmax, ylim=minmax, zlim=minmax)
    ax.set_title(surface.name)
    ax.set_axis_off()

    ax.add_collection3d(surface.shade().hilite(.5))

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This technique may also be used with parametric functions.  For example:

[image: Klein bottle]

where the code is:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import s3dlib.surface as s3d

# 1. Define function to examine ....................................
def klein_bottle(rtz) :
    r,t,z = rtz
    u = np.pi*(1-z)/2
    v = -t
    cU, sU = np.cos(u), np.sin(u)
    cV, sV = np.cos(v), np.sin(v)
    x = -(2/15)*cU* \
        (  ( 3 )*cV + \
           ( -30 + 90*np.power(cU,4) - 60*np.power(cU,6) + 5*cU*cV )*sU  )
    y = -(1/15)*sU* \
        (  ( 3 - 3*np.power(cU,2) -48*np.power(cU,4) +48*np.power(cU,6) )*cV + \
           (-60 + ( 5*cU - 5*np.power(cU,3) - 80*np.power(cU,5) + 80*np.power(cU,7) )*cV  )*sU  )
    z = (2/15)*( 3 + 5*cU*sU )*sV
    return x,y,z

# 2. Setup and map surface .........................................
img_fname, rez = 'data/earth.png', 7

surface = s3d.CylindricalSurface(rez, color='w' )
surface.map_color_from_image(img_fname)
surface.map_geom_from_op( klein_bottle, returnxyz=True )
surface.transform(s3d.eulerRot(90,-90),translate=[0,0,2])

# 3. Construct figure, add surface plot ............................
minmax = (-1.5,1.5)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(1))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.set(xlim=minmax, ylim=minmax, zlim=minmax)
ax.set_title(surface.name)
ax.set_axis_off()
ax.view_init(elev=20, azim=-125)

ax.add_collection3d(surface.shade(.5,ax=ax).hilite(ax=ax))

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The mathematical description of the geometry used in the code is from the Klein bottle [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle#Bottle_shape) page.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's introduce the floor function.

[image]

`theta` and `phi` increases "continuously" from `0` to `2*pi`. We can scale them to the dimensions of the matrix `a`, and use the property of the floor function to compute the indexes and extract the proper color from your matrix.

Here is the code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
import matplotlib

# random colors
theta_dim, phi_dim = 100, 30
a = np.random.random((theta_dim, phi_dim))

# Generating Torus Mesh
angle = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
theta, phi = np.meshgrid(angle, angle)
r, R = .25, 1.
X = (R + r * np.cos(phi)) * np.cos(theta)
Y = (R + r * np.cos(phi)) * np.sin(theta)
Z = r * np.sin(phi)

# compute the indexes
t, p = [var / (2 * np.pi) for var in [theta, phi]]
t = np.floor((t - 0.5) * a.shape[0]).astype(int) + 1
p = np.floor((p - 0.5) * a.shape[1]).astype(int) + 1
# extract the color value from the matrix
colors = a[t, p]
# apply a colormap to the normalized color values
norm = Normalize(vmin=colors.min(), vmax=colors.max())
cmap = matplotlib.colormaps.get_cmap("viridis")
normalized_colors = cmap(norm(colors))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection = '3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride = 1, cstride = 1, facecolors=normalized_colors)
ax.set_aspect("equal")
plt.show()
```

[image]